# JavaScript code doesn't work on Cordova App, but works on Ripple emulator

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

My Cordova Application works on this link http://autoskole.rs.sr/cordova/www/kategor.html but when I build it on android it seems it doesn't execute JavaScript code.

Any ides why is that not working?
Here is the code of file kategor.html

```html
<html>
  <head>
 
  <frame src="frame_a.htm" scrolling="yes">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/kategor.js"></script>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>
  <link href="css/tacniodg.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
 
  <script src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
    

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
      <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/angular/angular-mocks.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
 <script src="js/kategor.js"></script>
 <script src="lib/fastclick.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="js/services.js"></script>
 <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>

 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body ng-app="starter" style="margin-bottom: 98px;5" onload="function()">

  <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
    <button class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon" onclick="location.href='main.html';"></button>
        <h1 class="title icon-left ion-model-s" ><font size="5" face="Arial" >       Auto škola "Volan" </font></h1>
  
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content>
  </br>
<div id="container">

</div>
<div data-role='page'>
 <script>
 
  
   $(document).ready(function () {
    
    //uzima spisak autoskola..
    $("#container").html('');
    
    var autoschools = [];
    var categories = [];
    var tests = [];
    
    $.ajax( "http://autoskole.rs.sr/api/autoschools" )
    .done(function(data) {
    
     console.log(data);
     
     for(index in data) {
      var row = data[ index ];
      autoschools[ row.id ] = row;
      $("#container").append('<p><button style="background: #4b7a99; background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#6faed9), to(#4b7a99));  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #6faed9, #4b7a99); padding: 13px 26px;    -webkit-border-radius: 14px; -moz-border-radius: 14px; border-radius: 14px; -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 1px 0, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 1px 0; text-shadow: #7ea4bd 0 1px 0; color: #ffffff; font-size: 18px; font-family: helvetica, serif; " class="autoschools" id="'+ row.id +'" href="#">Pokreni Test</button></p>');
      
     }
    
     $(".autoschools").on('click', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault(); 
    
      var schoolId = $(this).prop('id');
    
      $.ajax( "http://autoskole.rs.sr/api/autoschool/" + schoolId )
      .done(function(data) {
    
       $("#container").html('');
       $("#container").append('<h2>'+ autoschools[ schoolId ].name +'</h2>');
       $("#container").append('<h3>Kategorije</h3>');
    
       if(undefined != data.categories && data.categories.length > 0) {
    
         for(index in data.categories) {
          var row = data.categories[ index ];
          categories[ row.id ] = row;
          $("#container").append('<p><button style="background: #4b7a99; background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#6faed9), to(#4b7a99));  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #6faed9, #4b7a99); padding: 13px 26px;    -webkit-border-radius: 14px; -moz-border-radius: 14px; border-radius: 14px; -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 1px 0, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 1px 0; text-shadow: #7ea4bd 0 1px 0; color: #ffffff; font-size: 18px; font-family: helvetica, serif; " class="categories" id="'+ row.id +'" href="#">'+ row.name +'</button></p>');
    
          if(undefined != row.tests && row.tests.length > 0) {
           for(var i in row.tests) {
             var rowt = row.tests[ i ];
             
             if(tests[ row.id ] == undefined) {
               tests[ row.id ] = [];
             }
             tests[ row.id ].push(rowt);
           }
          }
         }
         console.log(tests);
    
         $(".categories").on('click', function (e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           
           var catId = $(this).prop('id');
    
           $("#container").html('');
           $("#container").append('<h2>'+ autoschools[ schoolId ].name +'</h2>');
           $("#container").append('<h3>Kategorija - '+ categories[ catId ].name +'</h3>');
    
           for(index in tests[ catId ]) {
              var row = tests[ catId ][ index ];
              $("#container").append('<a href="pitanjanew.html"><p><button style="background: #4b7a99; background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#6faed9), to(#4b7a99));  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #6faed9, #4b7a99); padding: 13px 26px;    -webkit-border-radius: 14px; -moz-border-radius: 14px; border-radius: 14px; -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 1px 0, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 1px 0; text-shadow: #7ea4bd 0 1px 0; color: #ffffff; font-size: 18px; font-family: helvetica, serif; " class="tests" id="'+ row.id +' href="pitanja.html">'+ row.name +'</button></p></a>');
           }
           
           
         });
         
         function redirect()
            {
            var url = "pitanjanew.html";
            window.location(url);
            }
        }
       });
       
       return false;
      });
     })
     .fail(function() {
       alert( "error" );
     });
     
     //uzima spisak korisnika
     $("#load-users").on('click', function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
    
       $("#user-container").html('');
    
       $.ajax( "http://autoskole.rs.sr/api/test-users" )
       .done(function(data) {
         console.log(data);
    
         for(index in data) {
           var row = data[ index ];
    
           $("#user-container").append('<p>'+ row.name +'</p>');
         }
       })
       .fail(function() {
         alert( "error" );
       });
    
       return false;
     });
    });
</script>
  </div>
   
  
      
      </ion-content>

    </ion-pane>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to add a listener to a ['deviceready' event](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready) and run your code in it. This event fires when device is literally ready, but it is not the same as `$(document).ready` which tells when the DOM is ready.

Comment: @Michael Radionov Have tryed that but still doesn't work. Anyway thanks for suggestion. Any other idea?

Comment: It is difficult to guess. Try to use [Remote debugging](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging), you'll be able to actually see what error you have.